# SQL error after deploy ASP app

Tags: asp.net, sql, deployment, membership

Hi I have the problem to successfully log in my application after deploy.
I am using ASP MVC default login and membership provider and it is working on my localhost.
But after deploy I am trying to log in, then error is shown.

*

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)
>
> *Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> SQLExpress database file auto-creation error:  The connection string
>   specifies a local Sql Server Express instance using a database
>   location within the application's App_Data directory. The provider
>   attempted to automatically create the application services database
>   because the provider determined that the database does not exist. The
>   following configuration requirements are necessary to successfully
>   check for existence of the application services database and
>   automatically create the application services database:
>
> 1. If the
>      application is running on either Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008R2,
>      special configuration steps are necessary to enable automatic creation
>      of the provider database. Additional information is available at:
>      http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=160102.
> 2. If the application's
>      App_Data directory does not already exist, the web server account must
>      have read and write access to the application's directory. This is
>      necessary because the web server account will automatically create the
>      App_Data directory if it does not already exist. If the application's
>      App_Data directory already exists, the web server account only
>      requires read and write access to the application's App_Data
>      directory. This is necessary because the web server account will
>      attempt to verify that the Sql Server Express database already exists
>      within the application's App_Data directory. Revoking read access on
>      the App_Data directory from the web server account will prevent the
>      provider from correctly determining if the Sql Server Express database
>      already exists. This will cause an error when the provider attempts to
>      create a duplicate of an already existing database. Write access is
>      required because the web server account's credentials are used when
>      creating the new database.
> 3. Sql Server Express must be installed on the
>      machine.
> 4. The process identity for the web server account must have a
>      local user profile. See the readme document for details on how to
>      create a local user profile for both machine and domain accounts.*

*

If anyone knows how to resolve this, I will be really happy.
Thank you!

Comment: can you post some of your code? it could just be  problem with your connection string or how your calling your sqlConnection

Comment: Ok Jerad Rose, thank you, I am quite new here so I did not now anything about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you deploy this to an external webserver you must adjust your connectionstring settings in the web.config

Comment: thank you and how should I adjuct my connection string ?

This is my connection string to applicationservices what causes the problem, because without asp authentication it works.

<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: hard to say with the amount of information you have provided. Like @DWolf mentioned earlier: you need to provide code.

Comment: the connection string:
connectionString="Data Source=database-server;Initial Catalog=database;User ID=database-user; Password=database-user-password" 

you use Integrated Security=SSPI which uses your windows credentials.